# Python: classify objects in images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

```
camera = webcam; % Connect to the camera
nnet = alexnet;  % Load the neural net

while true   
    picture = camera.snapshot;              % Take a picture    
    picture = imresize(picture,[227,227]);  % Resize the picture

    label = classify(nnet, picture);        % Classify the picture

    image(picture);     % Show the picture
    title(char(label)); % Show the label
    drawnow;   
end
```

I found this matlab code in the internet. It displays a window with the picture from a webcam and very quickly also names the things in the picture ("keyboard","bootle","pencil","clock"...). I want to do that in python.
So far I have this:

```
import cv2
import sys
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

This is alreay very similar, but only detecting faces. The matlab code uses alexnet. I guess this is a pre-trained network based on imagenet data  (http://www.image-net.org/). But it is no longer available.
How would I do this in python?

(There has been a similar question here, but it is 4 yrs. old and I think there are newer techniques now).

Comment: The first example labels the whole picture with one choice of objects from 1000 classes. The second finds a only single class of object inside the picture but includes the location of each instance. Could you clarify that you want just to replicate the first example in Python? Combining the two is also possible (boxes around identified objects of multiple classes), but can get a fair bit more complex than either example.

Comment: I am only interested in "label = classify(nnet, picture);  % Classify the picture"
I.e. getting one classifaction label for the pciture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the "tensorflow" package and the pre-trained network "vgg16", the solution is quite easy.
See https://github.com/machrisaa/tensorflow-vgg/blob/master/test_vgg16.py